# Get object by id using $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am dealing with a little issue, and need some help.

I have an API setup, works just fine.

Now I want to get a single object using its ID. I have tried using `$http`, but could't get it to work. So I switched back to `$resource`. Here is what I have in my service file.

```
getPlatesInSelectedContainer: function() {
    return $resource('/api/v1/platesincontainer/:id', {id: "@id" },{
       get: { cache: true, method: 'GET' }
    });
},
```

And in controller I am reaching to function doing so.

```
CleaningPlatesFactory.getPlatesInSelectedContainer({id : 1}, function(data){
    $scope.plates = data;
    console.log(data);
})
```

But this is not returning any results. What I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Earlier I have tried $http but getting this.

[image]

Comment: You aren't accepting any parameters in your service function but you are passing the id in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would still get $http to work. It's as simple as this:

```
getPlatesInSelectedContainer: function(data)   {
    return $http.get('/api/v1/platesincontainer/' + data.id);
}
```

You need to accept the data object in your service function.

Comment: I have tried this method. its returning an empty data. Please Have a look at the update code. I have tested my URL dozen of times, and it returns data.

Comment: You need to accept the 'data' object in your service function.

Comment: Worked!  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Inside the service:

```
getPlatesInSelectedContainer: function(data) {
 return $resource('/api/v1/platesincontainer/:id', {id: data.id },{
   get: { cache: true, method: 'GET' }
 });
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
getPlatesInSelectedContainer({ id: 123 })
```

Comment: I gave this a try.   
    `CleaningPlatesFactory.getPlatesInSelectedContainer({id : 1}, function(data)
   {
     $scope.plates = data;
     console.log(data);
   });
` but getting nowhere. Simply nothing prints